# Ultra-precision switching

Tags: switches, precision

I have to switch a signal (uA to nA) between two precision resistors (stability 0.2 ppm/degC). Is this possible to do with electronics? We cannot do it with mech relay contacts because of stability problems (maybe oxide layer etc).

Comment: What are the values of the two resistors? What is their accuracy (tolerance)? What are the voltages involved? Is the signal dc or ac? If ac, what is the bandwidth?

Comment: Bandwidth about 20Hz, values between 2K5 and 250R, voltages vary from 0-15V both + and -. Measuring the voltage across each resistor provides a value for an analytical parameter. Which resistor is used determines the measurement range of the machine

Comment: Reed relays are how high-precision gear switch. Make sure you use a decent brand such as Coto.